# syntax of the command is incorrect - multiple if conditions in for loop

Tags: windows, batch-file, windows-7, scripting

This is my code:

```
for %%a in (%TESTS%) do (
    IF not "%%a" == "tests/xxxx/yyyy/zzzz/test1" (
    IF not "%%a" == "tests/qqqq/ssss/bbbb/test1892" (
    and so on...
    )
    )
)
```

If I have got about one hundred IF's condition I became getting such error:
"syntax of the command is incorrect"
And if I commented out few (any) IF line, the error is absent.

What is a problem with this code?

Greetings.

Comment: You should add an example where the error is reproducible. The code you've posted doesn't have any errors. Maybe the real code has some unescaped special symbols. Such nonsensical errors may also be displayed if you're trying to use a variable multiple times inside the loop, in which case [delayed expansion](http://ss64.com/nt/delayedexpansion.html) should be used.

Comment: The maximum length of a command is 8 KB (about 8190 characters). I suggest you to perform these multiple tests in another way. For example: insert all search strings in a file and use `findstr`.

Comment: It works with findstr option. I've already got file with all search string, so I use this solution.
However, I've got line in outputs from file which contains searching phrase. For example:

findstr /c:"%%a" Makefile
   IF errorlevel 1 (
    rem do smth
   )

My ouptputs (in console):
TESTS_LIST += test1
TESTS_LIST += test1892
 
Is there any possibility that this line won't be present in outputs after executing scripts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most propably you are exceeding the limit of 8192 characters for a command line/block.
So you could try the following:

```
for %%a in (%TESTS%) do (
    call :SUB "%%~a"
)
exit /B

:SUB
if "%~1"=="tests/xxxx/yyyy/zzzz/test1" exit /B
if "%~1"=="tests/qqqq/ssss/bbbb/test1892" exit /B
rem and so on...
echo do your action(s) here (done only in NONE of the listed strings match)!
exit /B
```

The `if` statements are inverted and do therefore not need to be nested.
Since the `if` lines are transferred to a subroutine `:SUB`, they are no longer part of an excessively long `for` command line/block.